# Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation + conditional jump

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have been searching for this bug, but just can't seem to find it.

Valgrind tells me this:

```
Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==31732==    at 0x4C28B35: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:261)
==31732==    by 0x406B87: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long void const*) (in /home/matija/Documents/FER/6.semestar/dna-assembly/FMindex/src/test)
==31732==    by 0x40560C: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (in /home/matija/Documents/FER/6.semestar/dna-assembly/FMindex/src/test)
==31732==    by 0x40497A: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&) (in /home/matija/Documents/FER/6.semestar/dna-assembly/FMindex/src/test)
==31732==    by 0x403B15: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&) (in /home/matija/Documents/FER/6.semestar/dna-assembly/FMindex/src/test)
==31732==    by 0x413655: Compressor::getMTF(std::string const&) (in /home/matija/Documents/FER/6.semestar/dna-assembly/FMindex/src/test)
==31732==    by 0x412EE4: Compressor::compress(std::string&) (in /home/matija/Documents/FER/6.semestar/dna-assembly/FMindex/src/test)
==31732==    by 0x40E2FB: Opp::Opp(std::string&) (in /home/matija/Documents/FER/6.semestar/dna-assembly/FMindex/src/test)
==31732==    by 0x402098: FMindex::FMindex(std::string&) (in /home/matija/Documents/FER/6.semestar/dna-assembly/FMindex/src/test)
==31732==    by 0x41DE0B: main (in /home/matija/Documents/FER/6.semestar/dna-assembly/FMindex/src/test)
```

For this piece of code. There seems to be an error while pushing to vector as far as I can tell from this message, but I just don't get it. I also get one "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value" error, I suppose it is consequence of this one.
Am I missing something?

```
vector<int> Compressor::getMTF(const string& L)
{
    // Construct initial MTF list
    list<char> MTFList = alphabet.toSortedList();

    // Generate MTF code for L
    vector<int> MTF; 
    for (int i = 0; i < L.length(); i++)
    {
        // If I am at the beginning of a bucket, store current MTF state
        if (i % bucketSize == 0) 
        {
           MTFStates.push_back(MTFList);    
        }

        // Find position of L[i] in MTFList and encode it
        list<char>::iterator it;
        int pos = 0;
        for (pos = 0, it = MTFList.begin(); it != MTFList.end(); it++, pos++)
           if (*it == L[i])
           {
              MTF.push_back(pos);
              MTFList.push_front(*it);
              MTFList.erase(it);
              break;
           }
     }
     return MTF;
}
```

Comment: `MTF.push_back(pos);` seems to be where the stack trace is coming from, and that looks fine. However, what the hell is a `unsigned long void const*`?

Comment: I just found this by JaredPar:

Another common cause for this I've just found is when you pass over some integer constants to a variadic function, which are put on the stack as ints, but when the callee gets it as longs, you've got a problem on 64-bit machines.

I was almost about to give up and just consider valgrind being stupid, then I've realised that simply casting it to long fixes it.

I am not sure what should I cast to long, pos or set definition of vector as vector<int>?

Comment: What variadic function are you referring to here?

Comment: @ildjarn I am not sure what is variadic function, maybe push_back() as it is probably template?

Comment: A variadic function is a function with `...` as the last parameter; `std::vector<>::push_back()` is definitely not a variadic function.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I really don't know where this long came from, maybe has something to do with 64-bit architecture?

Comment: `unsigned long void const*` is simply not a valid type. Maybe you're using a newer GCC than your version of valgrind supports?

Comment: @ildjarn: I am using valgrind-3.6.1-Debian and g++ 4.6.1

Comment: [This page](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html) indicates that support for GCC 4.6.x was only introduced in Valgrind 3.7.0, so I think my theory may be correct. Try updating Valgrind.

Comment: There is something wrong here. Unless the thing generating the type `unsigned long void const` is assembly that is being mislabeled, something is wrong.

Comment: @ildjarn: thanks for the idea, I believe this could be the reason as the overall program is executing correctly. I am having trouble with upgrading valgrind to 3.7.0 on Ubuntu 11.10 (some package dependencies are messed up) so I cannot confirm it yet.

Comment: @ildjarn Just tried with updated valgrind - still the same error. Still, thanks for the help!